# Mongo db "not okForStorage" error

Tags: javascript, jquery, mongodb, meteor

I'm trying to use collectionFS with cfs-ejson-file like so -

`Meteor.users.update({_id: Meteor.userId()}, { $set: { "profile.photo" : obj.imageObj}});`

to set a profile photo on a user, however i'm getting the error "not okForStorage".

Comment: what happens when you run `meteor mongo` in your meteor project directory (while meteor is running)?

Comment: Nothing shows up, this is weird because I can store imageObj in my other collection but for Users it's throwing this error

Comment: SOLVED - For some reason you have to use $push into an array for it to work, I hope this is solved in the future